# Find which pairs of records' positions can safely be switched in a combined set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the situation: I have a page where I can edit multiple records at once (Let's say invoices). They are not shown below each other, but they are edited like one record. At page load, values are displayed in a given field only when they are the same throughout the whole set of records.

Now, on top of that, I also want to edit child records (1-n relationship; lines of invoice). I managed to show the invoice lines records that are identical throughought all of the edited invoices, like so:

```
Invoice 1     Invoice 2                    Lines edited
   A             B                               D
   D             C                               G
   F             D               =>          
   G             E
                 G
```

Assuming A, B, ... are the lines of invoice

Ordering matters through the lines of the invoice, therefore each line of invoice has a position field. Here is what I want to do: allow reordering the lines of invoice. When editing one invoice, this is an easy task. But when editing multiple invoices at once, some issue(s) appears. Consider the following:

```
Invoice 1        Invoice 2                    Lines edited
   F(1)             B(1)                           F(1)
   A(2)             C(2)                           B(2)
   B(3)             D(3)               =>          C(3)
   C(4)             F(4)
   E(5)
```

When moving line F after line B, in Invoice 1, F is not only moved after B but also after A and the user doesn't know about it; in Invoice 2, F is already after B, but the user didn't know about it. So should B be placed right before F (at position 3) or stay where it is ? This is unclear.

What I want to do is prevent reordering when the behavior is unclear (or unexpected) and allow it in other situations. Here is my solution: For each line of invoice, find if it can be moved up one step (position--) and if it can be moved down one step (position++). How ? For each neighbour pair of lines in the edition page (in the example: F-B; B-C), if the corresponding pairs in the source invoices lines are neighbours and in the same order, the pair can be switched. So, in the example, that means B and C can be switched but not F and B. Therefore the result would be:

```
Lines edited    move down      move up
     F             no            no
     B             yes           no
     C             no            yes
```

Here is more or less my current situation:

```
CREATE TABLE [InvoiceLine](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [invoiceId] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [position] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [text] [nvarchar](255)  NULL,
    [price] [decimal](18,2)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceLine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)

CREATE TABLE [Invoice](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customerId] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)

INSERT INTO [Invoice]([customerId]) VALUES
(1000),
(2000);

INSERT INTO [InvoiceLine]([invoiceId],[position],[text],[price]) VALUES
(1000,1,'F',10.5),
(1000,2,'A',3.0),
(1000,3,'B',4.0),
(1000,4,'C',1.0),
(1000,5,'E',1.0),

(2000,1,'B',4.15),
(2000,2,'C',1.35),
(2000,3,'D',1.20),
(2000,4,'F',12.10);

DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000),(2000);

DECLARE @n int;
SET @n = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ids);

SELECT
    CAST(text AS nvarchar) AS id,
    CASE WHEN rank_position = _rankMain THEN position ELSE NULL END AS position,
    CASE WHEN rank_text = _rankMain THEN text ELSE NULL END AS text,
    CASE WHEN rank_price = _rankMain THEN price ELSE NULL END AS price,
    0 AS isRecordDeleted
FROM (
    SELECT
        T4.position, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text, T4.position ORDER BY id) AS rank_position,
        T4.text, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text ORDER BY id) AS rank_text,
        T4.price, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text, T4.price ORDER BY id) AS rank_price,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text ORDER BY id) AS _rankMain,
        _cnt
    FROM
    (
        -- Filter lines
        SELECT
            text,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(id) FROM InvoiceLine WHERE invoiceId IN (SELECT * FROM @ids) AND text = T2.text
            ) AS _cnt  FROM
        (
            -- add rank on text field (an invoice line is considered equal to another one if both text fields are equal)
            SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY text ORDER BY invoiceId) AS rnk, text FROM
            (
                -- distinct lines
                SELECT DISTINCT invoiceId, text FROM InvoiceLine WHERE invoiceId IN (SELECT n FROM @ids)
            ) T1
        ) T2
        WHERE rnk = (SELECT COUNT(n) FROM @ids)
    ) T3 INNER JOIN InvoiceLine T4 ON T4.text = T3.text
) T5 WHERE _cnt = _rankMain ORDER BY position
```

My question is:

**how should I transform that query (actually stored procedure) to get the "move up" and "move down" fields ?**

The first idea I had was to take all neighbour pairs from the result and find their distance in each source invoice lines (the distance being the absolute value of the position difference) and take the maximum of the distances. If the maximum is equal to 1 and the differences all have the same sign, then the pair's position can be switched. But then I don't know how to translate that to SQL...

[**EDIT**] One more thing: top edited record should always have move up = no while lowest edited record should always have move down = no.

[**EDIT 2012-02-23**] Added ORDER BY at the end of the query

[**EDIT 2012-02-23**]
Here is a second set of data an its expected output:

```
INSERT INTO [Invoice]([customerId]) VALUES
(1000),
(2000),
(3000);

INSERT INTO [InvoiceLine]([invoiceId],[position],[text],[price]) VALUES
    (1000,1,'F',10.5),
    (1000,2,'A',3.0),
    (1000,3,'B',4.0),
    (1000,4,'C',1.0),
    (1000,5,'E',1.0),
    (1000,6,'G',4.2),
    (1000,7,'H',9.0),
    (1000,8,'K',9.0),

    (2000,1,'B',4.15),
    (2000,2,'C',1.35),
    (2000,3,'D',1.20),
    (2000,4,'F',12.10),
    (2000,6,'G',4.2),
    (2000,7,'H',2.7),
    (2000,8,'I',1.3),

    (3000,1,'B',41.15),
    (3000,2,'C',15.35),
    (3000,3,'D',12.20),
    (3000,4,'F',11.10),
    (3000,5,'I',4.0),
    (3000,6,'G',4.2),
    (3000,7,'H',6.7),
    (3000,8,'E',7.3);


DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000),(2000),(3000);
```

Should Yield:

```
id  position  text  price   isRecordDeleted  moveUp  moveDown
B     NULL     B    NULL           0           no      yes
C     NULL     C    NULL           0           yes     no
F     NULL     F    NULL           0           no      no
G      6       G    4.20           0           no      yes
H      7       H    NULL           0           yes     no
```

[**EDIT 2012-02-24**]
And duplicated lines should appear only once and have moveUp and moveDown only if they are direct neighbours

Here is a third set of data an its expected output:

```
INSERT INTO [Invoice]([customerId]) VALUES
(1000),
(2000),
(3000);

INSERT INTO [InvoiceLine]([invoiceId],[position],[text],[price]) VALUES
    (1000,1,'F',10.5),
    (1000,2,'A',3.0),
    (1000,3,'B',4.0),
    (1000,4,'C',1.0),
    (1000,5,'E',1.0),
    (1000,6,'J',3.2),
    (1000,7,'G',4.2),
    (1000,8,'H',9.0),
    (1000,9,'K',9.0),
    (1000,10,'F',3.0),

    (2000,1,'B',4.15),
    (2000,2,'C',1.35),
    (2000,3,'D',1.20),
    (2000,4,'C',1.35),
    (2000,5,'F',12.10),
    (2000,6,'J',6.2),
    (2000,7,'G',4.2),
    (2000,8,'H',2.7),
    (2000,9,'H',3.1),
    (2000,10,'I',1.3),

    (3000,1,'B',41.15),
    (3000,2,'C',15.35),
    (3000,3,'D',12.20),
    (3000,4,'F',11.10),
    (3000,5,'I',4.0),
    (3000,6,'J',2.3),
    (3000,7,'G',4.2),
    (3000,8,'H',6.7),
    (3000,9,'E',7.3);


DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000),(2000),(3000);
```

Should Yield:

```
id  position  text  price   isRecordDeleted  moveUp  moveDown
B     NULL     B    NULL           0           no      no
C     NULL     C    NULL           0           no      no
F     NULL     F    NULL           0           no      no
J      6       J    NULL           0           no      yes
G      7       G    4.20           0           yes     no
H     NULL     H    NULL           0           no      no
```

Or better:

```
id  position  text  price   isRecordDeleted  moveUp  moveDown
B     NULL     B    NULL           0           no      no
C     NULL     C    NULL           0           no      no
F     NULL     F    NULL           0           no      no
J      6       J    NULL           0           no      yes
G      7       G    4.20           0           yes     yes
H     NULL     H    NULL           0           yes     no
```

[**EDIT 2012-03-02**]

The second result is better because although H appears twice in invoice 2000, both lines are neighbours, therefore it is safe to switch position of H and G: both H lines will be switched.

But this last result will probably result in an overcomplicated query.

Comment: +1 for giving us your table structure and data as a script. You'd be amazed at how much time that saves when trying to answer a question.

Comment: Hard to help because I can't visualize what the user is doing with your interface. What kind of app is this, what's the goal? Why are users editing multiple invoices at once? Do they see all these lines under the invoices as well as "lines edited"?  When values are displayed in a given "field"... what "fields" are you referring to? Do "lines edited" mean lines commonly found in all invoices? Does this list change as they use the interface? Why does a user need to know lines edited? When a user "moves a line", are they drag-n-dropping horizontally within an invoice?

Comment: @sisdog, answer 1: Actually, I'm creating something like an app generator (more like scaffolding and only partial for now). So this should apply to the generic case of 1-n relationships. Which is the case with invoices where 1 invoice can contain n lines of invoice.

Comment: @sisdog, answer 2: If you have n invoices, each addressed to a different customer, but containing the same text, and you need to correct a typo for instance, it's more convenient to correct them all at once.

Comment: @sisdog, answer 3: When in multi-edit mode, they only see the "lines edited".

Comment: @sisdog, answer 4: By "fields" I mean the different fields of the lines of invoice: the text, price, quantity, ...

Comment: @sisdog, answer 5: No, "lines edited" is the set of lines that show on the edit page in multi-edit mode and is computed so: include a line in the set of "lines edited" only if it exists in every invoice edited (the existence comparator is based on one or more fields of the child table; for the invoice example, it is based on the "text" field of the lines of invoice).

Comment: @sisdog, answer 6: I don't understand the question (wich list are you talking about ?)

Comment: @sisdog, answer 7: "Lines edited" are the lines show to the user for edition.

Comment: @sisdog, answer 8: Lines are shown in a table display, each line above the next one. Up and down arrows on each line will allow the user to move a line. But drag'n dropping could be an option, harder to implement though since a line could not be dropped between any two lines...

Comment: The questions getting kindof long, so I may be missing it - are we allowed to assume that the position numbers always form a set of 1..N where N is the number of rows for each invoice (i.e. no gaps, and each number used only once)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, we can assume the position number is the row number of a line of invoice for a given invoice, starting at 1.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (2000);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (3000);

SELECT il.* 
INTO #InvoiceLineQuery
FROM [InvoiceLine] il
INNER JOIN @ids i ON il.invoiceId = i.n


SELECT letter.text id,
       CASE WHEN pos.maxPos = pos.minPos THEN pos.maxPos ELSE NULL END AS position,
       letter.text,
       CASE WHEN price.maxPrice = price.minPrice THEN price.maxPrice ELSE NULL END AS price,
       0 AS isRecordDeleted,
       CASE WHEN moveUP.text IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS moveUP,
       CASE WHEN moveDOWN.text IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS moveDown
FROM (SELECT il.text
      FROM #InvoiceLineQuery il
      GROUP BY il.text
      HAVING count(il.position) = (SELECT count(1) FROM @ids)) letter
INNER JOIN (SELECT il.text, MAX(il.position) maxPos, MIN(il.position) minPos
            FROM #InvoiceLineQuery il
            GROUP BY il.text) pos on letter.text = pos.text
INNER JOIN (SELECT il.text, MAX(il.price) maxPrice, MIN(il.price) minPrice
            FROM #InvoiceLineQuery il
            GROUP BY il.text) price on letter.text = price.text
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT upNeighbour.text
            FROM (SELECT mainLine.text text, upLine.text upText
                  FROM #InvoiceLineQuery mainLine
                  INNER JOIN #InvoiceLineQuery upLine ON mainLine.position = upLine.Position + 1
                                               AND mainLine.invoiceId = upLine.invoiceId) upNeighbour
            GROUP BY upNeighbour.text,upNeighbour.upText
            HAVING count(upNeighbour.upText) = (SELECT count(1) FROM @ids)) moveUP ON letter.text = moveUP.text
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT downNeighbour.text
            FROM (SELECT mainLine.text text, downLine.text downText
                  FROM #InvoiceLineQuery mainLine
                  INNER JOIN #InvoiceLineQuery downLine ON mainLine.position + 1 = downLine.Position 
                                                 AND mainLine.invoiceId = downLine.invoiceId) downNeighbour
            GROUP BY downNeighbour.text,downNeighbour.downText
            HAVING count(downNeighbour.downText) = (SELECT count(1) FROM @ids)) moveDOWN ON letter.text = moveDOWN.text


DROP TABLE #InvoiceLineQuery
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't yield correct results. With the given data, line C should have moveDown = no but your query makes it a yes. I haven't explored your query yet so maybe is it only partially wrong...

Comment: Actually with the other set of data (see my last edit of the day), the results are not correct at all. So, nop, this is not it yet. Thanks for your time though....

Comment: If I understand you, lines can only move up when their up neighbour are the same in all invoice. And it work the same way with down neighbour?

Comment: yes, that's right. And ordering is based on the position field

Comment: Ok, this should work. I modified your query because frankly I don't like massive sub queries but if you want you can just use the 2 left join.

Comment: Ok, now it works better but it still doesnt work when using my other set of data but select only invoice 1000 and 2000. It yields only 3 rows (D,E,I) but it should yield 5 rows (B,C,F,G,H).

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm a little late on the update I was beat by the other guy ;( anyway it should work .. I think the other version worked for what you stated in your answer but no big deal.

Comment: Seriously I won't answer any more because I think you just use this to outsource some though code and you keep adding specifications. To do more than this I fell I should get paid ;). Good luck anyway. If you understand the code I did you should be able to modify it for your needs.

Comment: Ooops, now I feel awkward. I guess you're right, I've asked too much. Sorry... Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've lost sleep on this one. I think this works:

```
;with CommonLines as (
    select [text],
      MIN(position) as minPos,MAX(position) as maxPos,
      MIN(price) as minPrice,MAX(price) as maxPrice
    from @InvoiceLine
    where invoiceId in (select n from @ids)
    group by [text]
    having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @ids)
), InvoiceOrders as (
    select invoiceId,[text],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceId order by Position) as rn
    from @InvoiceLine where [text] in (select [text] from CommonLines) and
    invoiceId in (select n from @ids)
), AlwaysAdjacent as ( --Ignoring lines that aren't going to appear at all
    select a1.[text] as FirstText,a2.[text] as SecondText,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a1.[text]) as Ord
    from
        InvoiceOrders a1
            inner join
        InvoiceOrders a2
            on
                a1.invoiceId = a2.invoiceId and
                a1.rn = a2.rn - 1
    group by a1.text,a2.text
    having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @ids)
)
select
    cl.[text],
    CASE WHEN aa1.Ord IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MoveDown,
    CASE WHEN aa2.Ord IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MoveUp,
    CASE WHEN minPrice=maxPrice THEN minPrice END as price,
    CASE WHEN minPos=maxPos THEN minPos END as Position
from
    CommonLines cl
        left join
    AlwaysAdjacent aa1
        on
            cl.[text] = aa1.FirstText
        left join
    AlwaysAdjacent aa2
        on
            cl.[text] = aa2.SecondText
order by
    COALESCE(aa2.Ord,aa1.Ord),
    CASE
        WHEN aa1.Ord IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        WHEN aa2.Ord IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 2 END
```

I put the invoice data into a table variable also, and ignored invoice since it didn't seem relevant - setup data below.

Hopefully, it's reasonable easy to read, but some explanation anyway. `CommonLines` does a relational division against `InvoiceLine`, to find the `text`s that we're going to work with. `InvoiceOrders` then, for each invoice, calculates the order in which these `text`s appear - this ordering ignores any other rows, and is just based on `position`.

`AlwaysAdjacent` then performs another relational division, having used `InvoiceOrders` twice to determine those `text` values that appear in the same (relative) positions within all invoices - that is, the difference between their ordering is a constant, even if the absolute values are different.

Finally, we output the texts, and use `AlwaysAdjacent` to determine whether moving down or up should be allowed. The final `ORDER BY` is a bit tricky, but I think is correct - it's trying to accommodate longer runs than 2, where the middle rows can move both up and down (i.e. swap `F` and `E`'s positions in `1001` and F should appear between C and G, and the entire set can be reordered)

Result:

```
text MoveDown    MoveUp      price                                   Position
---- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------
F    0           0           NULL                                    NULL
B    1           0           NULL                                    NULL
C    0           1           NULL                                    NULL
G    1           0           4.20                                    6
H    0           1           NULL                                    7
```

---

Setup data:

```
declare @InvoiceLine table (invoiceId int not null,position int not null,[text] char(1) not null,price decimal(12,2) not null)

INSERT INTO @InvoiceLine([invoiceId],[position],[text],[price]) VALUES
    (1000,1,'F',10.5),
    (1000,2,'A',3.0),
    (1000,3,'B',4.0),
    (1000,4,'C',1.0),
    (1000,5,'E',1.0),
    (1000,6,'G',4.2),
    (1000,7,'H',9.0),
    (1000,8,'K',9.0),

    (2000,1,'B',4.15),
    (2000,2,'C',1.35),
    (2000,3,'D',1.20),
    (2000,4,'F',12.10),
    (2000,6,'G',4.2),
    (2000,7,'H',2.7),
    (2000,8,'I',1.3),

    (3000,1,'B',41.15),
    (3000,2,'C',15.35),
    (3000,3,'D',12.20),
    (3000,4,'F',11.10),
    (3000,5,'I',4.0),
    (3000,6,'G',4.2),
    (3000,7,'H',6.7),
    (3000,8,'E',7.3);

DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000),(2000),(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for that data, but it doesn't work when selecting only invoices 1000 and 2000. The result says C and F can be switched and F and G can be switched, which is wrong.

Comment: I've just updated my answer (because I was working on adding in the extra columns), but haven't looked into your comment yet. I'll take a look

Comment: @Daniel - I made a mistake on the `InvoiceLines` CTE - it should be limited to just the invoices of interest, so I've added an extra filter into the `WHERE` clause. Also, I've added in the price and position columns.

Comment: @Daniel - doh - sloppy edit on the first CTE. I've just re-edited, and re-run against the test data, so it should execute now.

Comment: I thought it worked but I found a case in which it doesnt work: when an invoice has the same line more than once (see my last edit). But, yes that's my bad as I forgot to mention it at first...

Comment: @Daniel - I can try and take another crack at it - is this definitely the last surprise spec change?

Comment: Well, as I said to the other guy, I guess I'm asking too much... So, if you really want to try, it would be great indeed and I won't add any more specs. But you've both helped me quite a lot already so I will content myself of your actual answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Damien_The_Unbeliever, here is a solution for result 1 of the third set of data (a solution for result 2 would be better):

```
DECLARE @InvoiceLine TABLE (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [invoiceId] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [position] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [text] [nvarchar](255)  NULL,
    [price] [decimal](18,2)  NULL
)

DECLARE  @Invoice TABLE (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customerId] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Invoice([customerId]) VALUES
(1000),
(2000),
(3000);

INSERT INTO @InvoiceLine([invoiceId],[position],[text],[price]) VALUES
(1000,1,'F',10.5),
(1000,2,'A',3.0),
(1000,3,'B',4.0),
(1000,4,'C',1.0),
(1000,5,'E',1.0),

(2000,1,'B',4.15),
(2000,2,'C',1.35),
(2000,3,'D',1.20),
(2000,4,'F',12.10);

DECLARE @ids TABLE(n int);
INSERT INTO @ids (n) VALUES (1000),(2000);

;WITH Lines AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(text AS nvarchar) AS id,
        position AS pos,
        CASE WHEN rank_position = _rankMain THEN position ELSE NULL END AS position,
        CASE WHEN rank_text = _rankMain THEN text ELSE NULL END AS text,
        CASE WHEN rank_price = _rankMain THEN price ELSE NULL END AS price,
        0 AS isRecordDeleted
    FROM (
        SELECT
            T4.position, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text, T4.position ORDER BY id) AS rank_position,
            T4.text, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text ORDER BY id) AS rank_text,
            T4.price, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text, T4.price ORDER BY id) AS rank_price,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T4.text ORDER BY id) AS _rankMain,
            _cnt
        FROM
        (
            -- Filter lines
            SELECT
                text,
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @InvoiceLine WHERE invoiceId IN (SELECT * FROM @ids) AND text = T2.text
                ) AS _cnt  FROM
            (
                -- add rank on text field (an invoice line is considered equal to another one if both text fields are equal)
                SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY text ORDER BY invoiceId) AS rnk, text FROM
                (
                    -- distinct lines
                    SELECT DISTINCT invoiceId, text FROM @InvoiceLine WHERE invoiceId IN (SELECT n FROM @ids)
                ) T1
            ) T2
            WHERE rnk = (SELECT COUNT(n) FROM @ids)
        ) T3 INNER JOIN @InvoiceLine T4 ON T4.text = T3.text
    ) T5 WHERE _cnt = _rankMain
),
LinesNoDuplicates AS ( -- All lines of invoice from the selected invoices that aren't duplicated in any of those invoices
    SELECT * FROM @InvoiceLine
    WHERE
        text NOT IN( -- Exclude texts that appear twice in an invoice
            SELECT text FROM ( -- texts that appear twice in an invoice
                SELECT text, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY text, invoiceId ORDER BY position) as rnk FROM @InvoiceLine WHERE invoiceId IN (SELECT n FROM @ids)
            ) T1 WHERE rnk = 2
        )
        AND
        invoiceId IN (SELECT n FROM @ids)

),
Switchables AS ( -- Which lines can be switched
    SELECT
        UpperLine.text UpperText,
        LowerLine.text LowerText
    FROM
        LinesNoDuplicates UpperLine INNER JOIN
        LinesNoDuplicates LowerLine ON UpperLine.invoiceId = LowerLine.invoiceId AND UpperLine.position = LowerLine.position - 1
    GROUP BY
        UpperLine.text,
        LowerLine.text
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ids)
)
SELECT id, position, text, price, isRecordDeleted,
    CASE WHEN SwitchUp.LowerText IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS moveUp,
    CASE WHEN SwitchDown.UpperText IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS moveDown
FROM
    Lines LEFT JOIN
    Switchables SwitchUp ON text = SwitchUp.LowerText LEFT JOIN
    Switchables SwitchDown ON text = SwitchDown.UpperText
ORDER BY pos;
```